# Multiple definition of function in the same place

Tags: c, c99, generic-programming

I am trying to simulate generics in C by having some preprocessor definitions for a `matrix` type. Here is an excerpt of that:

```
#define __matrix_struct(TYPE) \
  struct { \
    uint32_t sz; \
    TYPE **ptr; \
  }

#define __matrix_t(TYPE) matrix_ ## TYPE
#define __matrix_ptr_t(TYPE) __matrix_t(TYPE) *

#define __matrix_typedef(TYPE) typedef __matrix_struct(TYPE) __matrix_t(TYPE)

#define __matrix_allocator_name(TYPE) TYPE ## _matrix_alloc
#define __matrix_allocator(TYPE) \
  __matrix_ptr_t(TYPE) __matrix_allocator_name(TYPE) (uint32_t sz) { \
    uint32_t i; \
    __matrix_ptr_t(TYPE) m = (__matrix_ptr_t(TYPE)) malloc(sizeof(__matrix_t(TYPE))); \
    m->ptr = (TYPE **) malloc(sz * sizeof(TYPE *)); \
    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) { \
      m->ptr[i] = (TYPE *) calloc(sz, sizeof(TYPE)); \
    } \
    return m; \
  }

#define __matrix_deallocator_name(TYPE) TYPE ## _matrix_free
#define __matrix_deallocator(TYPE) \
  void __matrix_deallocator_name(TYPE) (__matrix_ptr_t(TYPE) m) { \
    uint32_t i; \
    for (i = 0; i < m->sz; i++) { \
      free(m->ptr[i]); \
    } \
    free(m->ptr); \
    free(m); \
  }

#define matrix_alloc_ptr(TYPE, SIZE) __matrix_allocator_name(TYPE) (SIZE)
#define matrix_dealloc_ptr(TYPE, PTR_NAME) __matrix_deallocator_name(TYPE) (PTR_NAME)
```

In another file, `byte_matrix.h`, I am trying to define a matrix of `uint8_t` values, as follows:

```
#include "matrix.h"

typedef uint8_t byte;

__matrix_typedef(byte);

__matrix_allocator(byte)
__matrix_deallocator(byte)
```

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
CMakeFiles/tictac.dir/game/board.c.o: In function `byte_matrix_alloc':
/home/victor/dev/pc/tictac/game/../matrix/byte_matrix.h:13: multiple definition of `byte_matrix_alloc'
CMakeFiles/tictac.dir/main.c.o:/home/victor/dev/pc/tictac/game/../matrix/byte_matrix.h:13: first defined here
CMakeFiles/tictac.dir/game/board.c.o: In function `byte_matrix_free':
/home/victor/dev/pc/tictac/game/../matrix/byte_matrix.h:14: multiple definition of `byte_matrix_free'
CMakeFiles/tictac.dir/main.c.o:/home/victor/dev/pc/tictac/game/../matrix/byte_matrix.h:14: first defined here
```

I cannot understand why it would point to times to the same line and complain about that definition, since every header I wrote has include guards. Could you please explain this to me? Also if you know of a better approach to my problem, please let me know. Thanks.

Also I need to compile with `-std=c99` if that matters in this case.

Comment: Did you try to run only the preprocessor?

Comment: Yes, I did run `gcc -E game/byte_matrix.h` and there is only one occurrence of `byte_matrix_alloc`

Comment: You are including `byte_matrix.h` in multiple compilation units, which means you get multiple function definitions. You need to make these functions `static`.

Comment: You can use two macros -- `__matrix_allocator_declare` for h-files and `__matrix_allocator_define` for one (selected by you) c-file.

Comment: @Groo this did it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ReAl you're right. I have to admit that I thought of that, but I haven't done it because I'm lazy and I didn't think of the implications it would have

Comment: If you don't use `static`, functions are by default `extern`. This means that you will have multiple functions named `byte_matrix_alloc` in your program. If you use `static`, then you are saying that this function is private to each compilation unit, i.e. each .c file gets it's own copy of the function.

Comment: @Groo could you please elaborate an answer on that? I think including ReAl's recommendations would be good too :)

Comment: Interesting, C11 (C99 successor) provides [type-generic expressions](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html).

Comment: @Amessihel if only I could compile with C11

Comment: @Victor: have a look at [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), it does a similar thing for many data structures (vector, hashtable, tree). However, it becomes quite easy to get carried away with preprocessor macros. Your code might get seriously convoluted once you go this path, so use it sparingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick  fix would be to add `static` to your function definitions. This will create a static copy of these functions in each compilation unit which references the header. If you want the functions to be inlined every time, this is the way to go.

An alternative way to do it would be to keep function declarations in a .h file, and actual definitions in a single .c file. This approach will avoid duplication, and the compiler will not inline them (unless your linker supports link time optimization).

The reason is that you are including this header file in multiple compilation units. After the preprocessor does all the textual replacements, you end up with actual separate function definitions inside your .c files. And if you don't specify that you want them to be `static`, they are by default `extern`, which means that now the compiler doesn't know how to differentiate them if some other part of the code wants to call them.

This is what you basically do whenever you create a header file: you create a list of declarations which will be included in many compilation units, but there is always a single extern definition in a single .c file.

Answer (score 2):

Another way (relative to the proposed by Groo) is to create two macros.

- `__matrix_allocator_declare` with just prototype of function -- for h-file(s)
- `__matrix_allocator_define` with function body -- for one (selected by you) c-file

This way requires to handle two macros and to not forget add function-body macro in some file, but (and it is more important for embedded applications on small microcontrollers) it guarantees that only one function instance will consume memory.